# How to populate browser's entire window/document with rectangles

Tags: javascript

I want to populate the entire window with rectangles, no matter what size of window it is. eg. If rectangles are 250px wide, and window is 1000px wide, then it shold be 4 rec. in one row. I managed to fill just one row. Here is the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
                width: 250px;
                height: 150px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                display: block;
                position: fixed;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function ubaci_div() {
                var sto = 0;
                var ipsilon = "px";
                for (var x = 0; sto < window.innerWidth; x++) {
                    var cet = sto + ipsilon;
                    var divovi = document.createElement("DIV");
                    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(divovi);
                    document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[x].setAttribute("id", "id1");
                    document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[x].style.left = cet;
                    sto += 250;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <p id="p" onclick="ubaci_div()">Klikni</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like he means the document.

Comment: @jHilscher - my comment was crafted with that in mind sir

Comment: 2 notes: it's "common sense" to name the iterator variable in a for-loop "i" (for index, not "x"). + Ids should be unique in a html document.

Comment: What if the window is 1001px wide? How many 250px rectangles should go in there?

Comment: actually the divs are 252px width;

Comment: actually browser window. Sorry for that.

Comment: Mister "Neo" Anderson! The point is: to give an answer not a comment!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cfckvvzw/9/

```
  function ubaci_div() {
    var i = 0;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var num = (h / 150);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      alert(num);
      loop();
      var br = document.createElement('br');
    }
  }

  function loop() {
    var sto = 0;
    var ipsilon = "px";
    for (var x = 0; sto < window.innerWidth - 250; x++) {
      var cet = sto + ipsilon;
      var divovi = document.createElement("DIV");
      document.getElementById("body").appendChild(divovi);
      document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[x].setAttribute("id", "id1");
      document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[x].style.left = cet;
      sto += 250;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Exactly. That is the simpliest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vc7w608m/

```js
var rectangleWidth = 250;
var rectangleHeight = 100;
var columnCount = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / rectangleWidth);
var rowCount =  Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / rectangleHeight);
console.log(columnCount, rowCount)
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
  var rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
  rowDiv.style.height = rectangleHeight + "px";
  rowDiv.style["white-space"] = "nowrap";
  rowDiv.style["overflow"] = "hidden";
  document.body.appendChild(rowDiv);
  for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
      var rectangle = document.createElement("div");
      rectangle.style.height = rectangleHeight + "px";
      rectangle.style.width = rectangleWidth + "px";
      rectangle.style.display = "inline-block";
      rectangle.style["background-color"] = "rgb(" + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ", " + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ", " + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ")";
      rowDiv.appendChild(rectangle);
    }
}
```